# Debug Azure SignalR with multiple people (not connecting with own localhost)

Tags: angular, azure, debugging, signalr

Recently I build an Azure SignalR application currently running locally on https://localhost:12345/ (inside a C# web API project).

I am consuming the Azure SignalR application in an Angular application.

Currently I am debugging the SignalR code with a colleague so often we are both running the the SignalR application in localhost. We notice that about 50% of the time the Angular code will connect to our own instance of localhost and about 50% of the time to the localhost of the other person. This causes all kinds of side effects, you have for example no guarantee that your own breakpoints in the SignalR code will be hit.

Has anyone experienced this issue as well? And is there a way to force Angular to connect to your own instance of the SignalR code (your own localhost)?

Comment: This is not an issue, it is expected behaviour... You can create a free tier Azure SignalR instance only for testing and connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior as both of you are connecting to the same Azure SignalR service instance. Only way is to either

- use your own separate SignalR instance for your own debugging

or

- self-host SignalR for local debugging (if too much hassle to use separate SignalR instance above). https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr

or

- (not your case though, but just FYI) run Azure SignalR emulator (currently in preview) locally and connect to it instead of the real Azure one. Please note that emulator works for serverless scenario like Azure Function. For details, https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/emulator.md